# React Router 6 duplicates content on nested routes that uses Outlet

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, outlet

I have the following routes:

```js
<Suspense fallback={<Loading />}>
    <PrivateRoute // Returns a <Route {...props} /> or redirects using <Navigate {...settings}/>
        authenticated={authenticated(authentication)}
        path="dashboard"
        element={<Dashboard />}
    >
        <Route path="one" element={<p>One</p>} />

        <Route path="two" element={<p>Two</p>} />
    </PrivateRoute>
</Suspense>
```

And the following dashboard:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="column" justify="center" alignItems="stretch">
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
        <Outlet />
      </Grid>

      <Grid item xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={12}>
        Test
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
```

Private route:

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ authenticated, state, ...rest }) => {
  return authenticated ? (
    <Route {...rest} />
  ) : (
    <Navigate
      to="/login"
      replace
      state={
        state
          ? state
          : {
              message: "...",
              origin: window.location.pathname,
            }
      }
    />
  );
};
```

If I access */dashboard* this renders "**Test**" twice, if I access */dashboard/one* it renders the `</Outlet>` component and "**Test**" twice, but if I remove `</Outlet>` it renders "**Test**" once... I'm not sure what is making it renders twice, I have seen [this](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts) example and everything looks ok

Comment: show ur `PrivateRoute` component plz

Comment: Added to the question, I think that the problem is related to suspense (from React), I would not like to remove it, but it looks like that I'll need to... I have read the releases notes of React Router and saw something about preload...